# Unable to connect to xampp server from android device

Tags: php, android, xampp, braintree

I am using BrainTree Payment service in my android app.For server ,I am using php and XAMPP. Now when I use emulator and access server with "http://10.0.2.2:80".

IP address, everything works fine but if I put my laptop's IP address(where server is running),it does't work on android device and emulator.

I am getting :

> "Connection Timeout Error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You !It turned out to be McAfee was blocking the connection request..SO after disabling McAfee,it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** make sure both your android device and your laptop are on the exact same wireless network. This has to be the same router so I would avoid testing in a public area where there may be many routers serving a network.

**(2)** sometimes your firewall  a might be blocking incoming connections, temporarily disable it.

**(3)** double check you're connecting to the correct IP address in your code. CMD -> ipconfig, then it's ipv4

Comment: Hi,checked all the above 3 steps,settings are correct.I even tried running the app in other wireless network which is quite fast..It gives "W/System.err: cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.1.89:80 timed out"..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the ipv4 that you see when you type ipconfig into command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Windows Defender, change Apache's `require all granted` config among others and try disabling the Windows firewall.